# Detach vs Sync In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have product,category and product_category table.I made relationship `many to many` . Now using `attach` method user select multiple categories for product and save it for `pivot` table. now my question is when user update categories for product which method is better to update `sync` or `detach` .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Better" depends on the situation; if you're detaching then attaching new records, `sync` will do both, otherwise, there's nothing wrong with using `detach` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to have all of the selected categories then it would probably be better to use sync rather than attach/detach for each.

Comment: what do you mean by select all categories. my question is that it all depend on user which categories have selected by user then which method is best to call

Comment: I mean if you are having the user select all related categories at once rather than individually it would be better to use sync. If they are selecting one at a time then you would need to use attach/detach.